# What is the meaning of "WIPE PATHS HO"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm reading a webtoon entitled Freaking Romance.
And in the second episode, there is a mat written "WIPE PATHS HO".
What is the meaning of this?
I would be grateful if someone tells me.

[Freaking Romance Episode 2](https://www.webtoons.com/en/romance/freaking-romance/episode-2/viewer?title_no=1467&episode_no=2)

Comment: It says "WIPE PAWS HO." I'm not sure what the "HO" part means - it is used as a derogatory word for "woman" (see meaning 6 [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ho), but whether that's what we have here, and whether it's addressed to herself or the cat, I don't know.

Comment: The comic strip is linguistic garbage anyway, clearly not written by a native speaker of English. I can't believe all the errors I've just noticed leafing through it are because of poor proofreading - it's written by someone who doesn't know any better. **Ho** there could be short for **House** (this is a house that you have to wipe your real or figurative paws before entering), or just a casual insult to any females who come visiting (**Ho = Whore**). Or something else. Who knows?

Comment: It doesn't look like the sort of cartoon where they would intend to use the word "whore" in any way.  I'd suggest writing to the authors and asking what it means.

Comment: One of the characters says "beechass". Sometimes written "beech ass", this is "gangsta" slang, I believe. This fits with "HO" meaning "woman".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that it means/tries to convey the Following:

a command for the **ho** reading this to wipe the paths

ho could mean whore, but I think it just means women in general

also, the reason that it didn't say `Wipe the Paths, Ho` could be because it is large text and it's on a mat which, doesn't exactly have the most spacious room to write *large* text

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actually read the word on the mat. Given it has a picture of a cat, and the foot appears to be obscuring one letter, I think "paws" is the most likely word.

[image]

Comment: So the meaning here is '(You) wipe (your) paws, ho'.